# How to pass saved card details from website to paytabs api

Tags: c#, jquery

I am using paytabs payment gateway. In my project we have card saving option
My question is how to pass selected card details in to paytabs api
Tokenization method used but did not get card details.

Comment: Did you get any solution? In our project of Mobile app, we need to provide the ability for the user "Add a new Card" feature. Also we need to support "Save Card" for future transactions.

Comment: yes i got the solution

Comment: Can you share the logical steps and API end points that you used to achieve this feature? I do not find a way out there to implement for the Mobile app